# Reg Expression htaccess RewriteRule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am new to using regular expressions for rewriting URL's in htaccess

I need to redirect mysite.com/123 to mysite.com/, IF cookie named 'ref' is set.

my current htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ref=true [NC]
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/$ http://www.mysite.com
</IfModule>
```

The goal is that when someone enters site with: mysite.com/111(some number) that they are redirected to the home page of the site after the cookie is set.

Comment: That expression is going to match `/123/` (note the trailing slash) -- are you testing with this? Does the redirect happen if you comment out the `RewriteCond`?

Comment: If I comment out the RewriteCond nothing happens, no redirect with www.mysite.com/1/ or www.mysite.com/1 etc.

Comment: Also, to confirm, yes I have been testing with both a / on the end and without.

Answer (score 1):

That rule will never match, since you're both in an `htaccess` file and have set a `RewriteBase`.  Both of those factors set a relative context that `RewriteRule` functions within - so it drops the leading slash on the match string.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ http://www.mysite.com/ [R=302,L]
```